# HILT lateinit property chatFragment has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am working with an app that has a Tab Layout with ViewPager2. I need to return an instance of the fragments in the FragmentStateAdapter's createFragment(...) method.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter (fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

**@Inject
lateinit var chatFragment: ChatFragment
@Inject
lateinit var searchFragment: SearchFragment
@Inject
lateinit var settingsFragment: SettingsFragment**

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment =
    when (position) {
        0 -> chatFragment
        1 -> searchFragment
        else -> settingsFragment
    }


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 3 //as we have 3 fragments
}}
```

I have constructor injected all of the fragments but Hilt shows the error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property chatFragment has not been initialized
```

at runtime.

The app runs fine when I manually return an instance of the fragments.

My MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

@Inject
lateinit var viewPagerAdapter: ViewPagerAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    //setting up the action bar
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarMain)//we set the toolbar as actionbar
    supportActionBar!!.title =
        "" 

    binding.viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
    val tabLayoutMediator = TabLayoutMediator(
        binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager
    ) { tab, position ->
        when (position) {
            0 -> tab.text = "CHATS"
            1 -> tab.text = "SEARCH"
            2 -> tab.text = "SETTINGS"

        }
    }.attach()
    
}
}
```

My module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object Module {

@Provides
@ActivityScoped
fun getViewPagerAdapter(@ActivityContext context: Context) : ViewPagerAdapter {
    return ViewPagerAdapter(context as FragmentActivity)

}

}
```

My fragments:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChatFragment @Inject constructor(): Fragment(R.layout.fragment_chat) {

private var _binding: FragmentChatBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    _binding = FragmentChatBinding.bind(view)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}


}
```

I really want to integrate Hilt in this app. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think there are multiple issues here. First, you should not do `@Inject` in Fragments / Activities, because this will cause a memory leak. Hilt would hold a reference to this fragment, even if its destroyed. Second, you are not constructor injection your dependencies inside your viewpager, but field injecting.

Comment: so the best way is to manually instantiate the fragments?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Ain't there tutorials on the internet in combination with dagger (hilt) and viewpager? I doubt there are non